# Does it hold that $f(x)=O(x^{k+1}) \implies f(x)=o(x^k)$?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Does it hold that

$$f(x)=O(x^{k+1}) \implies f(x)=o(x^k)$$

as $x\to 0$?

Comment: What happens when you try to prove it?  In this forum, you are supposed to show your efforts, not merely expect us to do it for you.  Can you first so a special case?  Say the case $k=0$ which says: if $f(x) = O(x)$ then $f(x) = o(1)$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: $|f(x)|\leq C|x| \iff |f(x)|/C \leq |x| \to 0$ since $x\to 0$. So this would imply $|f(x)|/C \to 0$, which is the meaning of $f(x)=o(1)$, if I'm not wrong somewhere.

Comment: What about $\,f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}\,$ and $\,k=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as $\frac{x^{k+1}}{x^k} = x$ and $x \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Use this to fill in the details yourself: If $f$ satisfies $f(x) \le Cx^{k+1}$ around a neighborhood of 0 then what about $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^k}$. And if the limit of this fraction is 0 [it is], then what is the definition of $o(x^k)$ again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.